# How to blacklist words in a HTML form? (I was wondering how I am able to blacklist certain words from being entered in my form)

Tags: html

I was wondering how I am able to blacklist certain words from being entered in my form. Specifically, the username field. I'm not sure if I need access to the PHP/JS files, but I have limited access to those.

```html
<pre>
    <div class="form-group"> 
      <label for="username" class="control-label">{{ lang('signup.username') }}</label> 
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" value="{{ data['login'] }}" name="RegistrationForm[login]" placeholder="Enter username">
'===                 
    </div>                 {% if name_fields %}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Firstly, help us to help you; please parse your code to be multi-line. Secondly, ANY validation needs to be done primarily server-side, e.g. via PHP, and, optionally, secondarily on the client-side i.e. in JS or via HTML5's Constraints API.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pattern` atribute. Though it is recommended to handle this server side as well!

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern="^((?!word1)(?!word2).)*$">

  <button type="submit">Submit
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stack Overflow! I did a little googling for you and I think what you are looking for a is a Bad Word filter - Here is an example https://codepen.io/mcfan/pen/xVVNwy - This example works on the basis of an array with the words you don't want to allow and checks that array upon submission.

```
// Enter the words to be filtered in the line below:
var swear_words_arr=new Array("bloody","war","terror");

var swear_alert_arr=new Array;
var swear_alert_count=0;
function reset_alert_count()
{
 swear_alert_count=0;
}
function validate_text()
{
 reset_alert_count();
 var compare_text=document.form1.text.value;
 for(var i=0; i<swear_words_arr.length; i++)
 {
  for(var j=0; j<(compare_text.length); j++)
  {
   if(swear_words_arr[i]==compare_text.substring(j,(j+swear_words_arr[i].length)).toLowerCase())
   {
    swear_alert_arr[swear_alert_count]=compare_text.substring(j,(j+swear_words_arr[i].length));
    swear_alert_count++;
   }
  }
 }
 var alert_text="";
 for(var k=1; k<=swear_alert_count; k++)
 {
  alert_text+="\n" + "(" + k + ")  " + swear_alert_arr[k-1];
 }
 if(swear_alert_count>0)
 {
  alert("The message will not be sent!!!\nThe following illegal words were found:\n_______________________________\n" + alert_text + "\n_______________________________");
  document.form1.text.select();
 }
 else
 {
  document.form1.submit();
 }
}
function select_area()
{
 document.form1.text.select();
}
window.onload=reset_alert_count;
```

You could of course change this to a keyup / keydown event but this should get you started.

Credit to @mcfan - Codepen